# Chess Clock as Birthday Gift Advice

Tags: chess-clocks

My boyfriend has an old beige/white Chronos II that needs repair. I've decided that perhaps purchasing a new clock for his birthday would be a better idea than my original idea (a chess coffee table book...really for me to improve the apartment decor!). But now after looking around I see it is very hard to acquire the Touch Chronos II. Can anyone recommend a suitable replacement? Hopefully one that complies with FIDE regulations and has tactile buttons.

Comment: Also: OR should I splurge on the the one listing of the Chronos II on eBay ($299 obo)?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Section 5.5 of the [FIDE handbook](https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/Standards_of_Chess_Equipment_and_tournament_venue.pdf) lists the following approved clocks:

> 5.5. **The electronic chess clocks endorsed by the FIDE**
> 5.5.1. DGT XL (year 2007)
> 5.5.2. DGT 2010 (year 2010)
> 5.5.3. Silver Timer (year 2007)
> 5.5.4. Sistemco (year 2009)
> 5.5.5. DGT 3000 (year 2014)
> 5.5.6. CE Clock (year 2017)
> 5.5.7. KK9908 Clock (year 2017)